# Downloading file from google cloud storage causes memory leak on nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, google-cloud-storage

I'm downloading from google storage on my nodejs service, I have an utility module that looks like this:

```
'use strict';

const BPromise = require('bluebird');
const logger = require('../../setup/logger');

module.exports = () => {

    let GCloudStorage = {};

    GCloudStorage.getStorage = () => {
        return require('@google-cloud/storage')();
    };

    /**
     * @param bucketName
     * @param filePath
     * @param destination the local disk destination
     */
    GCloudStorage.downloadFile = (bucketName, filePath, destination) => {

        return new BPromise((resolve, reject) => {
            const storage = GCloudStorage.getStorage();

            logger.info('Downloading file %s in bucket %s to local path: %s', filePath, bucketName, destination);

            const file = storage.bucket(bucketName).file(filePath);
            const config = {
                destination: destination,
                validation: false
            };

            file.download(config)
              .then(() => {
                logger.debug('Downloaded gs://%s/%s to %s', bucketName, filePath, destination);
                resolve(destination);
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                reject(err);
              });
        });
    };

    return GCloudStorage;
};
```

And then on my business code I'm using it like this:

```
let promises = [];
images.map(image => {
    promises.push(storageUtil.downloadFile(config.userFolder, image.image, path.resolve(`./reports/${reportId}/${image.name.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]/g, '')}`)));
});
return BPromise.all(promises);
```

When this process runs, the service augments its memory usage and it doesn't collects it during its lifetime.

I know this could be a nodejs issue with my code, but is there something I could do?